# ServiceStack not receiving values on OnDelete

Tags: servicestack

On OnDelete of ServiceStack, it is called but the values are empty.

I tried to check the value, e.g.

```
ProductRequestResponse rx = Client.Send<ProductRequestResponse>(
            "DELETE", "http://localhost:2012/api/product_request", 
            new ProductRequest { Id = 7 });
```

On the ServiceStack side, I only receive an Id of 0. Here's my StackService OnDelete method.

```
public override object OnDelete(ProductRequest request)
{
    throw new Exception("Id: " + request.Id.ToString());
}
```

Here's my objects use for communication

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductDto ProductDto { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRequestResponse
{
    public ProductDto ProductDto { get; set; }        

    public IEnumerable<ProductDto> ProductDtos { get; set; }

    public ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel.ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
}
```

What am I missing, why StackService is not receiving any value from OnDelete method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using the [Delete](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs#L697) method as the `Send` only does POST's:

So it looks something like:

```
restClient.Delete<TransactionLogResponse>("/transactionlog");
```

The reason why Delete doesn't expect a Request DTO is because the DELETE Http verb does not accept a request body.

If you want to add paramaters you should add this on the route path or query string, e.g:

```
restClient.Delete<TransactionLogResponse>("/transactionlog/1?Arg1=a&Arg2=b");
```